# Selecting direct children in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selector

How do you select all direct children of an element, not matter what type of element, in JavaScript?

Here's how you do it in JQuery:

```
$("#someID > *").addClass("some-class");
```

What is the JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: depending on your browser support matrix, you can always use querySelectorAll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) pretty much works the same way as the jQuery selector for most cases (not all, though!).
While traversing the resulting NodeList, `classList` property to set your respective class.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll( '#someID > *' );
for( var i=els.length; i--; ) {
  els[i].classList.add( 'some-class' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.getElementsById('someId').children,
  function (it) {
    it.classList.add('some-class');
  }
);
```